# Print list of all PAM modules traversed

Tags: pam

Is there a way to print a list of all modules that PAM processed by tweaking a global config option?

I have `[success=1/2]` for some modules and want to print the exact sequence of modules that were processed for a login to be successful. For simplicity, generating such a list for modules in `/etc/pam.d/linux` is sufficient.